# C# Process.Start cannot connect to server

Tags: c#, server, connection, snagit

I have a server with a bunch of installers on it. However my program stops when I attempt to initiate connection to the server.

```
Process.Start(@"\\{Server ip}\Software_Depot\Installers_Master\Snagit\v2019\snagit.exe");
```

What I'm trying to do here is initiate the installation of snagit.exe from our server.

Comment: So... Can you explain why you believe the error should not happen? I.e. what you get when you try the same from CMD?

Comment: I am able to ping the server just fine. and am able to connect to it no problem.

Comment: There is almost no correlation between ICMP and SMB... So what you get when you run "\\{Server ip}\Software_Depot\Installers_Master\Snagit\v2019\snagit.exe" from CMD on the same machine your program fails? (make sure to use exactly the same command as you would run from code - no cheating with picking one that you *feel* would run from code)

Comment: It would be funny if he is using impersonation in the program

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the elevated user that’s being used. If it’s a local admin account, it might not have permissions to the network share.
You could either add a “net use .... domain-user password” or use a domain account to launch your .net app.